# python call a function before every "continue"

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am writing many files each with many samples into a database.

My code is in this format:

```
files = find_my_files()

for file in files:
    try:
        check_file(file)
    except:
        logging.warning(f'{file} did not pass the check, skipping this file')
        continue
    try:
        process_file(file)
    except:
        logging.warning(f'{file} did not pass the processing, skipping this file')
        continue
    samples = get_samples(file)
        for sample in samples:
            try:
                check_sample(sample)
            except: 
                logging.warning(f'{sample} did not pass the checks, skipping this sample')
                continue
            try:
                write_to_db(sample)
            except:
                logging.warning(f'could not write{sample} to the database, skipping this sample')
                continue
```

I am looking for a way to save all the samples that I have skipped. This might be a single sample or a list of samples if a whole file is skipped.

My go-to solution is to create a function and call it every time before `continue`, but I wonder if there is a better way?

Comment: There is really no better way if the functions all return generic `Exception`, if they raise more specific exception types you may just wrap them all in a single `try..except` block and generate the log messages based on the exception type all in one go in the handler.

Comment: Did you try writing logic to make a list of the samples that are **written**, and then seeing which samples from the original list **aren't** in that list?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel That's actually a good idea, I can do that and it will keep the code much cleaner, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I think the simplest solution would be:

```
try:
    completed_successfully = False
    try:
       ....
    except:
       .....

    try:
       ......
    except:
       ......
 
    try:
       write_to_db(sample):
       completed_successfully = True
    except:
       ......

finally:
    if not completed_successfully:
        .....
```

Comment: I wished I knew why someone gave me a -1 on this. The user indicated that they wanted an action to happen in all circumstances except one.  This is a perfect use for try: finally:

Comment: This does not achieve what OP asked because it doesn't actually _reduce_ the line count, the `except` block inside the `try` block without a corresponding `raise` statement will result in execution follow through to the next statement (rather back to start of the loop) - thus no better than a `continue` statement. The whole point of the structure OP did was to _abort_ execution for all subsequent steps if the current step failed (and start next one).  What OP wanted _cannot_ be done without correcting the methods they are calling to raise unique exceptions and act on that in a single block.